# Symfony2 Doctrine2 : querybuilder bad query

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

New to Symfony2 and Doctrine2, i have a function in my entity repository to search entities after form submission. Input is array $get that contain form fields like $get['name'] = 'aname'.

My problem is that when i request with an id, or an id and a name, it's ok by with only a name, all my entities are matched because the query that has been build have no where clause.

Here is my code :

```
public function search(array $get, $flag = False){
/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$alias = 'd';

/* DB table to use */
$tableObjectName = 'mysiteMyBundle:DB';

$qb = $this->getEntityManager()
  ->getRepository($tableObjectName)
  ->createQueryBuilder($alias)
  ->select($alias.'.id');

$arr = array();

//Simple array, will grow after problem solved
$numericFields = array(
   'id');

$textFields = array(
    'name');


while($el = current($get)) {
    $field = key($get);

    if ( $field == '' or $field == Null or $el == '' or $el == Null ) {
        next($get);
    }

    if ( in_array($field,$numericFields) ){
        if ( is_numeric($el) ){
            $arr[] = $qb->expr()->eq($alias.".".$field, $el);
        }
    } else {
        if ( in_array($field,$textFields) ) {
            $arr[] = $qb->expr()->like($alias.".".$field, $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$el.'%') );
        }
    }

    next($get);
}

if(count($arr) > 0) $qb->andWhere(new Expr\Orx($arr));
else unset($arr);

$query = $qb->getQuery();

if($flag)
  return $query;
else
  return $query->getResult();
}
```

The query generated with only a name (ex "myname") input is :

```
SELECT d0_.id AS id0 FROM DB d0_
```

It should be:

```
SELECT d0_.id AS id0 FROM DB d0_ WHERE d0_.name LIKE '%myname%'
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related, but do not use "OR" or "AND" operators, because they have a different meaning that the classic "&&" or "||". cf http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

So, first, replace "AND" by "&&", and "OR" by "||".

Comment: Oh didn't know that. Thank you. I added 'data' => Null in my controller for the form fields, so now they are always set to Null as default. But it changes nothing :( Also put the two "if" in a conditional statement : "if ( !empty($field) && !empty($el) ) {" but doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the [setParameter method](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql)

```
$query->where('id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id);
```